# how to interact the video in java selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, chromedriver

I have a test case with video.

**Test Case scenario**:

There I want to check whether the link in the website and when we clicked that link played video link are same.

[![Highlighted is linked to video][1]][1]

[image: This is the video that played when clicking the link above]

I try something like this but I not worked.

```
JavascriptExecutor excute = (JavascriptExecutor) driver ;

        String asset=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@ng-repeat='asset in arParameters.assets']/a")).getText();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@ng-repeat='asset in arParameters.assets']/a")).click();
        //Thread.sleep(5000);
        String link =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//video[@name='media']/source")).getAttribute("src");
        excute.executeScript("alert('"+link+"')");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.get(baseUrl+"productions/cue_sheets/diag?ws=b54fb782-5865-408e-8f54-b1dea2d622c0&id=32c8aedd-b522-4580-b393-651f295fa1c0");

        try {
            assertEquals(link,asset);
        } catch (Error e) {
            verificationErrors.append(tcID+": "+e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: What did happen? Did it give any error? If no error is returned, check those two url.

Comment: @shahid just video is play.next line not worked.if pause the video.it throws time out error.